# Getting error in this python code while printing renamed files

Tags: python, file-rename

It is a code to rename all the files in a given directory but it seems while running in my terminal it giving me a syntax error at the print statement. Also if I comment the statement I get an error at the if statement of main. If I remove that too I get an error at the rename_files() function call statement.

```
import os

def rename_files():

    #Get all the files from directory
    file_list = os.listdir("/Users/arpitgarg/test")
    print file_list

    #Rename all the files.
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0123456789")
        print file_name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rename_files()
```

Comment: Is that really the indentation you're using? Also, you're clearly missing a `)`.

Comment: print traceback of your error. But, I think it identation problem in `__main__()`

Comment: Yea I figured the missing ). Sorry about that.. But what's with the indentation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt the trace back error is 'can't find the file specified', if so your py script needs to know where the files to rename; cause its not in the current working directory.
You'll have to add:

```
os.chdir('the exact path to files to be renamed')
```

before the for loop

Answer (score 0):

The file_names function does not contain a properly indented statement . Neither does the if **name**=='**main**' conditional. Also, the os.rename function call is missing a closing parenthesis . Try using a IDE next time , like pyCharm. It will highlight these syntax errors to you.

Answer (score 0):

When asking for help, provide us with the necessary information to help.. in this case the actual Traceback.

As stated before, the indentation is one major error. Python uses whitespace to differentiate code blocks. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Indentation

I recommend using PyCharm, as also stated before, but it is a memory hog.  If running on an older computer, I would recommend using Notepad++ or PyScripter.

Comment: I know that you have not enough reputation to leave comments, but your current answer should have been one.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for when I hit the quota that makes no sense.  Leaving an answer should require more "reputation" than a comment.